# Silverlight - HTML Markup and Javascript inside the application

Tags: c#, jquery, html, silverlight

Can I have HTML markup and javascript code existing inside a Silverlight application? For example can I have a JQuery accordion inside Silverlight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silverlight has a HTML control, but it's own animation capability is far more powerful than a simple JQuery accordion.

Once you move to Silverlight you will unlikely go back to using JQuery (I didn't) :)